# Totally stuck trying to get HTTPS data using Ruby on Windows

Tags: ruby, https, web-scraping

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and trying to write a Google Play scraper loosely based on [this one](https://github.com/tdoyle/Google-Play-Unofficial-Gem). I am having a really hard time with the HTTPS part of it.

Basically, using `Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://play.google.com/store/#{type}/details?id=#{id}"))` (as in the original gem) failed on Windows, for reasons explained on [this thread](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=36340).

So, I tried implementing the solution from that same thread, but it is really not working at all. I've even stopped trying with HTTPS for now, because there must be something basic I am missing on even just HTTP.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
  url = URI.parse( "http://google.com/" )
  http = Net::HTTP.new( url.host, url.port )
  http.use_ssl = true if url.port == 443
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
  res, data = http.get ("http://google.com/")
  puts data
```

In this case, I get nothing. Not even "nil", just no output at all.

However, when I just do a straight `Net::HTTP.get_print URI('http://www.google.com')`, I get the output, no problems.

Any help would be most appreciated. The real solution I am looking for is a simple way to scrape Google Play pages when using Windows -- this is just a step on the way there. So, if you know of a simpler way to accomplish this, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: What is `res, data` supposed to do? I understand the `data =`, but what is `res,` before that? Looking at other questions about `ruby` and `http` or `http` just shows `variable = http.get(URI)`.

Comment: I have no idea -- I copied it off the page I linked to. I tried it as just "data" as well, but it didn't work either.

Comment: `nil` won't print as "nil" unless you do something like  `puts data.inspect`, but it is indeed `nil` in this case.  @richoffrails has the correct answer

Comment: Do yourself a favor and use mechanize instead of net/http.

Comment: Mechanize is awesome but there's nothing wrong with using net/http, especially for learning :)

Comment: Thanks, trying Mechanize right now.

Comment: (After trying) Mechanize is giving me different errors, even with just the copy/pasted example off http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/EXAMPLES_rdoc.html -- skipping it for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting `nil` is because `data` doesn't have anything assigned to it. This line is only assigning to `res`:

```
res, data = http.get("http://google.com/")
```

Also, Google must be accessed using `http://www.google.com` with the `www` otherwise all you get back is a 301 redirect message and  `Net::HTTPMovedPermanently` object.

Comment: Thank you for this. I changed my code to say `data = http.get ("http://www.google.com/")
    @@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(data)` but now I get `C:/Users/ezuk/.pik/rubies/Ruby-193-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5-x86-mingw32/lib/nokogiri/html/document.rb:120:in `parse': undefined method `empty?' for #<Net::HTTPFound 302 Found readbody=true> (NoMethodError)` -- still completely lost here.

Comment: The reason you're getting that error is because ``Nokogiri::HTML`` is expecting a ``String`` object of HTML and you're passing it a ``Net::HTTP`` object. Do this instead and it should work: @@doc = Nokogiri::HTML(data.body)

Comment: Woo! Progress!! This is working, thank you so much! 

The next part of the problem is that for some reason, `data = http.get (url)` doesn't work, even though I set `url = URI.parse( "http://www.google.com/" )` right before. When I use the string itself as the argument, it works just fine. Any idea why?

Thank you so much for your help so far!

Comment: The reason for that is when you do ``url = URI.parse("http://www.google.com")`` you get back a ``URI::HTTP`` object and not a string, which is what http.get needs. Luckily ``URI::HTTP`` objects have a super handy ``to_s`` method so if you do ``data = http.get(url.to_s)`` it should work.

Comment: Wow! Absolutely made my evening -- I was frustrated beyond belief, and now it works and I can keep moving! Thank you so much! Accepting the answer of course.